# Php weird rounding

Tags: php

Simple question: Why this behavior:

```
var_dump($calc_product);
var_dump($calc_price);
var_dump(round($calc_product,1));
var_dump(round($calc_price,1));
```

gives:

```
float(16.05) float(16.05) float(16) float(16.1)
```

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like the first one is rounding down, while the second one is rounding up. Can you show some context for where the floats are actually set? The only thing I can think of is that $calc_product is actually 16.049999999 or something similar which var_dump is rounding to 2 dec-places.

Comment: Can't reproduce. Always returns `16.1`.

Comment: working perfect  here : `float(16.05) float(16.05) float(16.1) float(16.1) `

Comment: did not know that var_dump is rounding to 2 dec-places.. Will check it out. Thanks!

Comment: have you tried http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use floats for money.

A common method is to store the price in pence/cents, then to divide by 100 on display. This means you can use integer arithmetic instead, and avoids this issue.

Comment: That's OK! It's worth getting an understanding of floats, but for things that absolutely have to be exact (i.e. money!), they aren't a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

Read

#### [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) and

#### [money_format](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php)...

sure it will helps you. :)